# Dynamic array of structures in dynamic array of structure in C

Tags: c, arrays, csv, struct, realloc

I need to allocate array of unknown number of users, and each user must have array with unknown number of choices. All data is read from a CSV file.

So far, I have:

```
typedef struct wybor            //struct choice
{
    char rozmiar_kawy[2];
    char czy_z_mlekiem[4];
    char ile_cukru[2];
    char godzina[20];
}wybor;

typedef struct user
{
    char id[5];
    char imie[20];
    wybor *tablica_wyborow;     //dynamic array of struct choice
}user;


void odczyt_z_pliku(user **tab, int n);     //reading from file csv
void godzina(user *kawa);               //doesnt matter :p

int main() 
{
    int licznik = 0;            //counter for number of users
    user *tablica_userow;       //dynamic array of struct users
    tablica_userow = NULL;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pl_PL");

    odczyt_z_pliku(&tablica_userow, licznik);

    getchar();
    printf("%s", tablica_userow[0].tablica_wyborow[2].rozmiar_kawy);        //check if it works
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void odczyt_z_pliku(user **tab, int n)
{

    int i = 0;
    (*tab) = malloc(1*sizeof(*(*tab)));
    tab[n]->tablica_wyborow = malloc(1*sizeof(*(tab[n]->tablica_wyborow)));
    FILE *plik;
    plik = fopen("users.csv", "a+");

        //start reading from file and its working until...
        fscanf(plik, "%[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %s\n", tab[n]->id, tab[n]->imie, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].rozmiar_kawy, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].czy_z_mlekiem, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].ile_cukru, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].godzina);
        i++;

        tab[n]->tablica_wyborow = realloc(tab[n]->tablica_wyborow,(i+1)*sizeof(*(tab[n]->tablica_wyborow)));

        fscanf(plik, "%[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %s\n", tab[n]->id, tab[n]->imie, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].rozmiar_kawy, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].czy_z_mlekiem, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].ile_cukru, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].godzina);

        i = 0;
        n++;
        *tab = realloc(*tab,(n+1)*sizeof(user)); //...now, here there is a memory writing location error

        tab[n]->tablica_wyborow = malloc(sizeof(*tab[n]->tablica_wyborow));

        fscanf(plik, "%[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %s\n", tab[n]->id, tab[n]->imie, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].rozmiar_kawy, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].czy_z_mlekiem, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].ile_cukru, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].godzina);
        i++;
        tab[n]->tablica_wyborow = realloc(tab[n]->tablica_wyborow, (i + 1) * sizeof(*(tab[n]->tablica_wyborow)));

        fscanf(plik, "%[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %s\n", tab[n]->id, tab[n]->imie, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].rozmiar_kawy, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].czy_z_mlekiem, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].ile_cukru, tab[n]->tablica_wyborow[i].godzina);

    fclose(plik);

}
```

I don't know why I can't realloc array of users properly.

I didn't free the memory because it crashes when I tried.

Comment: In `odczyt_z_pliku` you have `tab[n]` which is wrong. It should be `(*tab)[n]`. And then `(*tab)[n]` is not a pointer but an actual structure instance, so you should not use `->` to access its elements.

Comment: And why do you have four identical `fscanf` calls? What if there's more data in the file? Or less? How about a loop?

Comment: `wybor *` is a pointer, not an array. But it can point to the first element of an array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have four fscanf just for testing, of cours there will be a loop. I will check your soution, thanks!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It works ! Thank you so much for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use linked lists to read in the data. The user data structure has a pointer to a linked list of the user's choices.

If you then still want to use arrays, you can now count the numbre of users, allocate an array for it and populate it with the users. In the same way you can count the number of choices of a user and allocate an array for it, then populate it.

Your linked list should have a `void *` member that will store a pointer to a separate data structure for users, so you can just move the pointer of the user data structure from the linked list to your array.

The user data structure has a member `wybor *tablica_wyborow;` for user choinces. You can maintain one linked list that will hold the user choices while reading in the data, then, once all of a user's choices have been read, you count them and allocate an array for it and copy the choices data (by value or pointer) into it.

Once everything is done, deallocate the linked lists as you no longer need them.

Alternativly, you can read the file for counting, then reprocess it. But that gives problems counting the individual user choices.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that just today morning. I was writing a counting function waiting for help from you :D